# Python Selenium: Driver source does not show loaded frame even after waiting

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to load and write some content from a webpage I am running in Selenium. The page has content inside a frame. Even when I wait for the frame to load, the only output I get is the javascript inside the frame. I can clearly see my content in the browser DOM so not sure why it is not loading in Selenium page_source or attribute innerHTML.

```
driver.get(page_src)
driver.switch_to_default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame("report")

delay = 10 # seconds
try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'my_content')))
except TimeoutException:    
    print("Took too long")

response = driver.find_element_by_id("my_content").get_attribute('innerHTML')
filename = 'results.html'
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(response)
```

Comment: Can you add time.sleep(10) before finding the response element? Please tell me what happen.

Comment: @Buaban That worked actually, but from what I understand that is not the best approach, waiting for an element is better way to do it.

Comment: Thanks. I intended to tell you the way to use wait, but I need to know some details first. In your case, I presume that `(By.ID, 'my_content')` existed in the beginning, but the content is not there yet. You may need to wait for visibility of some elements in the content.